# Programatically Re-sizing Office Content App

Tags: office-app

I am developing an Office content app (Office 2013) to visualize the data. This app has several settings and  shown in the user interface where users can make the changes via this user interface.

My problem is If the app is re-sized into smaller size it is very difficult to view the items in the settings page. Therefore the app should be re-sized into a larger size, modify the settings and re-sized back. This is not practical for a dashboard which has several copies of App.

My requirement is, when I click the settings button the App should be enlarged into a specific size, Do the changes and re-sized back into the original size again.

It would be great if some one could help me to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible, see [changing-width-and-height-of-content-pane-that-contains-an-iframe](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e4780e84-f8cb-44e6-b5ec-f3a490dce61b/changing-width-and-height-of-content-pane-that-contains-an-iframe)

To improve usability, you probably have to redesign your app. For example, you could open a new window (not an app) in which the user can do the settings.

Comment: I couldn't find any material/help for opening a new window from the office app. Please share if there are any resources for this

Comment: I haven't tested it, but `window.open(...)` should work. Unless MS sandboxed it away.